# One inch kick technique

Tags: technique, kicking, sparring

How can you train a one inch technique kick? When can it be used? Is it practical in real street fight and sparring. If there are videos for the tutorial I'll highly appreciate it. Why does the one inch punch is more popular than the one inch kick?

Comment: wish Bruce Lee was alive to answer it 0:)

Comment: That's a lot of questions. You may want to focus on 1 to prevent this question from becoming too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wing Chun has a training method that can lead to a 1 inch kick capabiity except it is not widely known or trained due to it being viewed as an advanced technique. The training method falls under "chi gerk" aka sticking legs. There are many videos on "chi gerk" as guidance.

The 1 inch aspect comes from countless hours of drilling the legs both the supportive and attack part so that after contact and deflection are made short range counter kicking can be applied through the use of pistoning the supporting leg or rotating the hips. This is why it is rare to see because it needs a lot of training to the point where single leg pistol excercises are easy to apply.

As for its practicality, it is a useful method for counter kicking and can be practical. The weakness is that a take down can neutralise the legs quckly making this training method more of a transient excercise. There are many example videos of wing chun being taken down in an mma fight.

Answer (score 3):

If you can deliver significant power from one inch, this is a huge advantage in fighting.

- Most people cannot produce significant power at very close ranges. A common way to nullify striking is to close distance, but this doesn't help against people who can whack you effectively at very close distances.
- Attacking at one inch leaves no reaction time for a defender. The eye cannot register an attack at this distance before the strike lands.
- Successive attacks can be very fast, including multiple strikes with the same weapon.

You are not going to find video tutorials on how to develop this kind of power helpful. It is the culmination of years of training.

The punch is more popular than the kick because of the available targets. If your feet are on the ground, the only targets you can have for a one inch kick are your opponent's feet and ankles. Anything higher than that is going to be farther away, which will nullify the advantage of being able to strike effectively at very short distances. You have two hands, which can move independently of your feet, that are considerably less predictable than your feet.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do an inch punch, you need to state your legs appropriate position to get a better punch.Can you punch well when you stand on your one leg?
that's why inch punch is more popular than the other.
standing in balance is very important to kick or punch.